# Calling Templated Function Overload of a Parent class with a Derived Class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, overloading

I have a problem of the following form:

```
class A {
    ...
};
template <...> class B : public A {
    ...
}

f(A*) {...}
f(C*) {...}
template <...> f(D*) {...}
```

The issue is that if I call the function f with an argument of type B*, it chooses the generic type D* (which isn't related to A or B at all).  I *want* it to choose the specialization for A*.

Is what I'm trying to do valid, and, if so, why isn't it working?

Comment: Do you mean `B<T>*? And what is `C*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what I want to do isn't directly possible; apparently template specialization takes precedence to polymorphism, and working around that isn't possible without Boost or C++11.

In the end, I solved the problem simply by casting everything to type "A*", before calling "f".

Thanks everyone,

Answer (score 2):

You can use SFINAE:

```
template<typename T>
typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_base_of<A, T>, Ret>::type
f(T*);
```

(If you want to disable this overload for the type `B` specifically and not just all types derived from `A` you can use `boost::is_same<B, T>` as the condition.)

Comment: This is a better answer if you are want all the derived types of `A` to resolve to `f(A*)`. Note that, with C++11, you can avoid a boost dependency by using std::is_base_of. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of

Comment: I'm trying to avoid dependencies on either Boost or C++11.

Comment: @IanMallett Reimplement said features yourself (although going for `is_base_of` is likely to be too much of a hassle, you can instead use `is_same`).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. You might try:

```
void f(B *b)
{
  f(dynamic_cast<A*>(b));
}
```

This will make a call to `f()` with a parameter of type `B*` resolve to your first definition of `f()`, the one that accepts a parameter of type `A*`. Otherwise, the compiler will resolve a call to `f()` with whichever function requires the least implicit type conversions. Since `template <typename D> void f(D*);` requires no type conversions, it will catch all invocations of `f()` that do not match a more specific definition.

Comment: Unfortunately, the type A is in a library, and the type B derived from it is a user-defined type.  The function "f" is also supposed to be in the library, and I don't want the user to have to define their own overloads.